# Retrieving object sent through a Message Queue

Tags: c#, message-queue, remoteobject

I am building a Queue system and I have been able to send an object to a public queue located on another server.
What I cannot figure out is how to rebuild the object on the receiver side (I have the its definition on both ends).

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you deserialize your object the same way you serialized it to put it in the queue?

Comment: I am not serializing it, just using queue.Send(commObject, "Notification mail");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the following MSDN example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y918yfy2(v=vs.110).aspx

Basically, calling `queue.Send(object)` serializes the object with the default `XmlMessageFormatter`.
So you'll have to deserialize the message using the same serializer, and cast the result of the received `Message.Body` to the good type:

```
// Connect to the a queue on the local computer.
MessageQueue myQueue = new MessageQueue(".\\myQueue");

// Set the formatter to indicate body contains an Order.
myQueue.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] {typeof(MyProject.Order)});

// Receive and format the message. 
Message myMessage = myQueue.Receive(); 
Order myOrder = (Order)myMessage.Body;
```

Comment: @user1648371 You can specify multiple types, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10798997/870604